# Using firestore in colab with python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, google-colaboratory

i'm trying to use firebase in colab with Python. But there is unsolvable error,
so i need some help.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore


cred = credentials.Certificate('/content/myKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred) # error in this line
db = firestore.client()

ValueError: : The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.
```

What can i do for solving this problem?

i also found similar answer with this, so i tried some many tips in there, like below.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

if not firebase_admin._apps:
  cred = credentials.Certificate('/content/foodle-94e80-firebase-adminsdk-zr21t- f02504e9fb.json')
  firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
else:
  app = firebase_admin.get_app()

db = firestore.client(app) # new error in this line
```

but new error is confusing me.

> DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a default instance of the Firebase app getting initialized somewhere. When the default instance gets created, it uses GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS instead of the credentials you pass in manually.
You can either provide GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the script, or ignore the default instance of the firebase app and create an explicitly named one.

**To create an explicitly named app**, change your code to provide a name:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore


cred = credentials.Certificate('/content/myKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(credential=cred, name='myApp') 
db = firestore.client()
```

**To provide GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and use the default app**:

If you're running your python script from the console, you can provide a value for that by running

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/content/myKey.json'`

In colab, you need to add this to your script:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/content/myKey.json"
```

After this you can run your second example.

(To get the credentials JSON go to [this page](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts), select your firebase-adminsdk service account, click 'ADD KEY', 'Create new key', select JSON as your option and download the resulting file.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked with

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/LALALA.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```